# prevent browsing web page by copying and pasting the url

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

How to prevent user from browsing web page by copying and pasting the URL in another browser in
 `asp.net silverlight`?

Comment: It can be a client-side blocking via JavaScript. For server-side, you can invalidate the session.

Comment: use login page and validate user by session